# Removing default WP Widgets from my Custom Sidebar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am registering a new Sidebar and by default WP adds default Widgets into it, how can I remove those widgets from my custom sidebar ?

unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Pages');

the above code completely deleted it from Admin Panel, I just want to remove from my custom side bar with id: my-custom-sidebar once registered it should remove default widgets (or any selected widgets that I want to remove)...

I have searched everywhere, found unset() as well, but didnt find the right answer to remove those Default widgets when I need to with a function. Basically, I am registering a new Sidebar and importing widgets into it, but all my custom widgets are imported including all default widgets by WP.

Comment: To clarify.. when you register a brand new sidebar, it automatically has widgets in it? That is unusual; this might indicate the name you are using for the sidebar was previously used, and had these widgets in it, and these widgets are still connected to the sidebar in the database.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the name is "Default Sidebar" and the id is : my-default-sidebar...

Comment: And if you try a different id?